# dividing two custom tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have quite a lengthy SQL query. This query returns two columns, `pop2068` and `ratio`. The query is as follows:

```
with CTE as
(
    select 
        name,  
        (select 
             sum(c.population * (select power(p.population_growth/100+1,50))) 
                                 from country c 
                                 join population p on c.code = p.country 
                                 where code in (select country
                                                from encompasses 
                                                where continent = continent.name)) as pop2068, 
       (select sum(population) 
        from country 
        where code in (select country 
                       from encompasses 
                       where continent = continent.name)) as ratio 
    from 
        continent
) 
select * 
from CTE
```

Running this query returns this result:

```
       name        |              pop2068               |   ratio
-------------------+------------------------------------+------------
 Asia              |    7688004586.16569723635392885320 | 4415908810
 Australia/Oceania | 474230639.524099258085328372951611 |  289808388
```

However I would like the `ratio` column to be `pop2068/ratio` instead.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Best wishes!

Comment: Hint:  `select  pop2068/ratio`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mabye you may use this at last query.

I mean you may use this.

```
with CTE (name,pop2068,ratio) as
(
    select name
    ,  
    (
        select sum(c.population * (select power(p.population_growth/100+1,50))) 
        from country c 
        join population p 
            on c.code = p.country 
        where code in
        (
            select country
            from encompasses 
            where continent = continent.name
        )
    ) as pop2068
    , 
    (
        select sum(population) 
        from country 
        where code
        in
        (
            select country 
            from encompasses 
            where continent = continent.name
        )
    ) as ratio 
    from continent
) 
select name,pop2068,(pop2068/ratio) as ratio from CTE
```

Comment: I don't quite understand where you mean when you say "last query". Could you elaborate where you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can give alias;

```
select pop2068/ratio as pop2068ratio from CTE
```